# UI Automation: How to get the value from this text box?

Tags: autohotkey

I have been messing around with UI Automation and I don't seem to getting anywhere.
I am looking to get this `Edit` control value. Using the **UI Viewer** utility I am able to get its value:
[image]

But actually doing this in a script has proven to be frustrating. Descolada's documentation is excellent, I think I am just messing up somewhere. Here is what I have:

```
UIA := UIA_Interface()                                                                          
PDFXEdit := UIA.ElementFromHandle("ahk_exe PDFXEdit.exe") 
documentEl := PDFXEdit.FindFirst("Name=Page")
documentEl.Highlight()
```

But nothing happens. I have tried the debugging features of VSCode to see what is stored in them. `PDFXEdit` seems to be a copy of `UIA` , `documentEl` is just an empty string:
[image]

I would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (Replace WINDOWID with the window's automation ID):

```
UIA := UIA_Interface() ;Initialize UIA interface
PDFXEditClass := UIA.GetRootElement().FindFirstBy("automationId=WINDOWID").ClassName
PDFXEdit := UIA.ElementFromHandle("AHK_class " PDFXEditClass)

documentEL1 := PDFXEdit.FindFirstBy("ControlType=Edit AND Name='Page' AND AutomationId='cmd.view.PageNumber@'").Value
```

Then documentEL1 is set as the variable with the value.